# Authorization: users able to edit their own details when loggedin

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have an application where I want Volunteers to be able to help with a Ceremony.

I would like them to be log in and click a button, this brings them to a page where their details appear and a list of Ceremonies they can apply for. I have that page working but I have no way of getting the current user logged in.

Also, for clarification: I have a Volunteer entity which holds the data and then a separate user entity. The username for a Volunteer is the same as their user entity.

I want to:

1. Compare the Username to the Volunteer Username and get the
   VolunteerId.

   2.This will then be used to edit/join a ceremony for that particular volunteer.

Here's my Volunteer Controller methods:

```
// GET: 
    public ActionResult VolunteerCeremony(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }



        string userName = string.Empty;

        var getVolunteerId = (from u in db.Volunteers
                              where WebSecurity.CurrentUserName == u.Username
                              select u.VolunteerId).SingleOrDefault();


        Volunteer v = (Volunteer)(from k in db.Volunteers
                       where getVolunteerId == k.VolunteerId
                       select k).SingleOrDefault();


        if (v == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        PopulateAssignedCeremonyData(v);
        return View(v);
    }

    // GET: 
    public ActionResult VolunteerHub()
    {
        return View();

    }


    // POST: /Player/VolunteerCeremony/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult VolunteerCeremony(int? id, string[] selectedOptions)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        var getVolunteerId = (from u in db.Volunteers
                              where WebSecurity.CurrentUserName == u.Username
                              select u.VolunteerId).SingleOrDefault();


        var v = (Volunteer)(from k in db.Volunteers
                                  where getVolunteerId == k.VolunteerId
                                  select k).SingleOrDefault();

        try
        {
            UpdateVolunteerCeremonies(selectedOptions, v);

            db.Entry(v).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (RetryLimitExceededException /* dex */)
        {
            //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
        }


        PopulateAssignedCeremonyData(v);
        return View(v);
    }
```

And then my Razor pages, the first which I want the user to click a link to bring them to the edit/join ceremony page:

```
@model PIMS.Entities.Volunteer

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "VolunteerHub";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<li>@Html.ActionLink("Join Ceremony", "VolunteerCeremony", "Volunteers", null, new { id = @model.VolunteerId })</li>
```

This gives me an error on the `new { id = @model.VolunteerId }`

Then the page which I want to get to:

```
    @model PIMS.Entities.Volunteer
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "VolunteerCeremony";
}

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<h2>Apply for Ceremony</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.VolunteerId)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VolunteerRole, "Volunteer Role", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.VolunteerRole, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VolunteerRole)

            </div>
        </div>
        </div>



        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-2">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label class="control-label">Assigned Ceremonies</label>
                @Html.ListBox("selectedOptions", (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.SelectedCeremonies, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-1" style="text-align:center">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="button" id="btnRight" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="button" id="btnLeft" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label class="control-label">Available Ceremonies</label>
                @Html.ListBox("availOptions", (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.AvailCeremonies, new { @class = "form-control" })

            </div>

            <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />


        </div>
        <div style="text-align:center;">

        </div>

}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/multisel")
}
```

Does anyone have any experience with this as it sort of key to my application!

Comment: What sort of authentication scheme are you using?  windows and forms auth are going to put the user information in the User property on the controller.

Comment: Using Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth;

Comment: and the controller.User property is empty?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: if you add this line in your controller action  var test = this.User;  what is the value?

Answer (score 0):

in mvc there is something called session variables, its just like app.config variables, you declare them like this in the controller

```
 Session["Volunteer"] = "volunteer1";
```

once declared they will remain declared for the entire session.

then you write code for the logoff to reset the Session variable to something that your code handles as no-one logged in or just null.